# Using User Set Variables to Create an Instance of a Class

Tags: c++

I was wondering if anyone had any advice on how to take a user input from a std::cin and enter it into a variable. The variable would be used to add an object to a class. Thanks!

This is the code I tried but it did not seem to work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "POI.h"

std::string create_file;

int main() {
    std::cout << "Name the File You Would Like to Create: ";
    std::cin >> create_file;
    POI create_file;
    create_file.poi_add(create_file, 1, 12, 7, "unknown");
    std::cout << create_file.poi_name();
}
```

Comment: You inner variable `create_file` shadows the outer variable with the same name.

Comment: You define `create_file` twice in different scopes, shadowing each other.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use **operator overloading**. In particular, you can overload `operator>>` as shown below. With this you can directly use `std::cin` with a `POI` type object.

```
class POI 
{
   private:
       std::string name ;
  //overload operator so that std::cin can be used with this class 
  friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, POI&);
};
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, POI& obj)
{
    is >> obj.name ;
    
    //check if input succeded 
    if(is )
    {
        //do somethind 
    }
    else 
    {
        obj = POI(); //leave the object in default state;
    }
    return is;
}
int main()
{
    POI p; 
    std::cin >> p;//this will use the overloaded operator>>
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the `if` and `else` is provide to **validate** if the input succeeded. If the input fails, then the object is left in a default state.

---

Additionally note that your inner variable `create_file` shadows the outer variable with the same name.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! I have two questions that is about the `is >> obj.name`. does that assign the variable "is" to the POI attribute name? Also, how does `std::cin >> p;` work? Does that set all attributes equal to the character input. How do you control what attribute the character input changes. Thank You!

Comment: @JackParent  Consider one example. `int i; std::cin >> i;`. Here the input is taken from the user and is put inside variable `i`. Similarly, `std::cin >> p;` does the same thing. Input is taken from user and is put inside variable `p`. Moreover, same goes for `is >> obj.name;`. In this case the input is taken from `is` stream and put inside the data member named `name` of object `obj`. For more example, you can refer to [overloading `operator>>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/overloading-the-input-operator-for-your-own-classes?view=msvc-170).